# gmapping node ignores tf2 static latch transforms

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: this seems to be true on any senor or odometric transformation requiring a link that is defined using a tf2 static latch transform. They work if defined using the static-transform-publisher but not if defined as tf2 latches. Can some confirm or reject this before I open ticket.

gmapping node ignores tf2 static latch transforms.
If I code this transform as a tf2 static latch it is ignored but if specified via node input as shown below then the scanner data is transformed correctly.

Note: the tf node above follows the my odometry node in the launch file that was issuing the same transform as a tf2 static latch in its main. It is the first node started in the launch sequence. Moving my latch transforms after gmapping node in the launch file made no difference.

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    { 
      ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_odometry");
    
      // send static latch transformations 
    
      tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster static_broadcaster;
      geometry_msgs::TransformStamped msg;
    
      msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
      msg.transform.rotation.x =  0.0;
      msg.transform.rotation.y =  0.0;
      msg.transform.rotation.z =  0.0;
      msg.transform.rotation.w =  1.0;
    
      msg.header.frame_id = "base_link";   
      msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
      msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
      msg.transform.translation.z = 0.1;
      msg.child_frame_id = "camera_link";
      static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);
    
      msg.header.frame_id = "camera_link";   
      msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
      msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
      msg.transform.translation.z = 0.2;
      msg.child_frame_id = "hokuyo_frame";
      static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);


  //    msg.header.frame_id = "base_link";   // additional test transform
  //    msg.transform.translation.x = 0;     // but should not be needed as chain is
  //    msg.transform.translation.y = 0;     // hokuyo_frame->camera_link->base_link
  //    msg.transform.translation.z = 0.2;   // transforms are all specified
  //    msg.child_frame_id = "hokuyo_frame";
  //    static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);
    
      msg.header.frame_id = "camera_link";   
      msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
      msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
      msg.transform.translation.z = 0.3;
      msg.child_frame_id = "camera_frame";
      static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);
    
    
      PublishOdometry sp;
    
    
      ros::spin();
    
      return 0;
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84451/gmapping-node-ignores-tf2-static-latch-transforms/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened a tick on gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-10-30**:
This is related to setting tf2 static latch transforms in code and is related to question http://answers.ros.org/question/92026/static-latch-frames-not-shown-in-tf-frame-graph/.